# Menú de navegación con logo responsive

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

**Estimados(a)**

Me encuentro haciendo un menu de navegación con logo y responsive pero nose como se anexa el logo (IMAGEN) y hacerlo responsive.

Si esta en sus posibilidades decirme se los agradecería.

Saludos y gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Por favor mostrá lo que tenés hecho o lo que intentaste.

Comment: Hola @Ernesto, te invito a hacer un [tour] en el sitio para que ganes tu primera medalla y consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener una respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo una solución en base a la poca información que planteas.

Para que tu imagen (logo) se pueda adaptar de forma automatica segun el tamaño de la pantalla para que sea responsive debes usar solo `css` de la siguiente forma:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src='' alt='' title='' />
```